# Laravel 8 how to call child relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-blade

i have a 2 table for relationship. **Product** as **parents** and **ProductImage** as **child** .
in this case i want to show ProductImage when im doing loop foreach data in blade. her emy code

this is Product model :

```
 public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class, 'product_id','id');
    }
```

this is ProductImages as child model :

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id','id');
    }
```

This is my blade views for showing data

```
  @foreach ($products as $product)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$loop->iteration++}}</th>
                    <td><img src="{{ asset('images/'.$product->images->image_name) }}" class="rounded d-block" width="150px"></td>
                    <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>
                    <td>
@endforeach
```

and this is my ProductController :

```
 $products = Product::with('images')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

when i try to do `<img src="{{ asset('images/'.$product->images->image_name) }}"`  , it's returning error like this `Property [image_name] does not exist on this collection instance.` `

so my summary question is, how do i call children class in my blade?

Comment: You have multiple images, so you should create a for loop for displaying it in your blade, or get a single image. `@foreach($product->images as $image) ...`

Comment: for this case , i just want to displaying single image

Comment: So, pick an image, for example pick first image by `$product->images->first()->image_name`

Comment: it's work but it's just for first row from all my data right? what if i want to show each image from different data?

Comment: You can put it inside a loop or use `pluck()` method. Overal, I suggest you to read about [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections)